# If one's body is clean but what about mind?

Tags: allah

I hear god wants his devotee to be cleaned all the time so what about one's weird mind?
Or there's no matter what is on someone's mind?

Comment: Can you please define "weird mind" ?

Answer (score 0):

Salam, Allah loves both physical and spiritual purification. Since our body is visible, it is easy to keep our body pure and clean. But the purification of soul/heart is subtle, invisible and hence difficult. Especially in these times, we only focus on your bodies. To know about the signs, symptoms and cures of the diseases of heart, here is the [best book](http://data.nur.nu/Kutub/English/Hamza-Yusuf_Purification-of-the-Heart.pdf) to purify our hearts.

Anyway, it depends upon what type of weird thinking you are talking about. I enlist few with possible treatment:

1) If it is about Allah(like thinking that whether God exists or not) or doubts about the divine guidance, then you should often recite 'La Hawalah wala quwatah) and first kalimah. Also, you should acquire more knowledge about Islam to strengthen your faith. You should sit with pious and knowledgeable people.It will take you from six things to six things: doubt to certainty; ostentation in your acts to sincerity; heedlessness to remembrance; desire for this world to desire for the Hereafter; arrogance to humbleness; and a bad internal nature to an excellent one. Bad thoughts about God is satan.

2) If it is about people, then refer to above book page 60 (Topic:Negative thoughts).

3)If it is about fantasy (like sexual etc), then refer to above book  page 36(Topic: Fantasizing). The practical remedy is to stop all the things which leads to fantasy like movies, porn, music etc. Do exercises, go for a walk.

At the end, Allah will not ask you about your thoughts which come unintentionally , on which you don't have control. He won't ask you about the whisperings of satan. But you give practical shape to your thoughs, then you would be asked about the actions. Salam.

Comment: I think body doesn't matter clean or dirty tell me only one thing if one's mind is not in control it is wandering somewhere so what is benefit of praying. root cause is only mind.

Comment: Unintentional thought won't come if mind is pure. that's I think absent in islam. And me I am an atheist believe in nature and humanity.

Comment: Prophet Muhammad(blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it.”

Comment: You will not be asked about the bad thoughts which cross your mind unless yu act upon it or speak of it. My colleague has the same problem as yours but she keeps praying and doing all the good things. I know it is disturbing but what matters at the end of the day is your actions.

Comment: But one won't speak that gonna kill someone else and eventually will slaughter at the end of the day and prayed all the day doesn't that matter?